# CSS fix for navbar collapsing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I know this is an issue many have had, but not being familiar with Less and being new to Bootstrap, I am looking to an all CSS solution for keeping my navbar from collapsing below 768 px:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid header-top">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left list-inline contact-links">
          <li><a href="tel:180042762687"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href='****live chat**'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:***@***"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
          </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline account-and-cart-links">
        <li><a href="my-account.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="my-cart.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
      </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing by collapsing you mean turning into a mobile-type nav bar (if not can you post fiddle or screenshots)? You need to remove all of the `.navbar` related items in your CSS media query 768px.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/blisstdev/U5h32/1/   If you view in full-screen and shrink the screen, you will see the top bar suddenly becomes two rows as suggested here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar , but I can't figure out how to actually fix it using their solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pull-left` and `pull-right` to the `<ul>`'s.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5h32/4/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid header-top">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left pull-left list-inline contact-links">
            <li><a href="tel:180042762687"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone">
                </span></a></li>
            <li><a href='****live chat**'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:***@***"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right list-inline account-and-cart-links">
            <li><a href="my-account.html">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="my-cart.html">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are the best!  thank you so very much!  I remembered that pull-left/right had been deprecated but it turns out it was only for dropdown menus!